# Simplifying nested STL container traversals

Tags: c++, stl

I have a code with nested traversals involving STL containers. In particular I have a top container ( a list) which contains sublists and those sublists contain further sublists. For e.g. In a DICOM structure, a patient can have multiple Studies and each Study can have multiple Series. I have to perform some operation on Series objects and the only way to reach them is to drill down deep in a loop as shown below.

The pseudocode looks like this.

```
STLContainer top;
STLContainer::iterator top_iter;

for ( top_iter= top.begin(); top_iter != top.end(); ++top_iter) {
 STLContainer mid = *top_iter;
 STLContainer::iterator mid_iter;

 for ( mid_iter = mid.begin(); mid_iter!= mid.end(); ++mid_iter) {
  STLContainer bottom = *mid_iter;
  STLContainer::iterator bottom_iter;

  for(bottom_iter = bottom.begin(); bottom_iter != bottom.end(); ++bottom_iter){
     ExecuteSomething(*bottom_iter); // Finally do something with the stored object
  }
 }
```

}

Now If I have to execute a series on operations repeatedly on these 'bottom' objects, I have to do this traversal again and again. If i wish to use STL Algorithms, I would need to write atleast 3 lines of "for_each" for each level of nesting.

Does anyone know of a technique to shorten this code which can work a bit like this?

```
// Drills down to the deepest nested container
for_each(top.begin(), top.end(), DrillDownAndExecuteOnBottom());
```

which can work in just one single line? Something like this?
Thanks!

Comment: There used to be a _Boost proposed_ iterator that flattened nested containers.

Comment: You can make a generic `iterate` template that works on both single objects and containers (or even single objects, single-element containers and map-type containers) and which performs the actual operation on the single element, but iteration on a container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the containers aren't all of the same element type:

```
struct DrillDownAndExecuteOnBottom
{
  template<typename T>
    void operator()(T& t) const
    { for_each(t.begin(), t.end(), *this); }

  void operator()(Bottom& b) const
  { ExecuteSomething(b); }
};
```

This will do a depth-first traversal until it reaches `Bottom` objects.

Comment: I prefer this one, thanks Jonathan, JAB and Brangdon for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

You can write your traversal once and encapsulate it using lambdas.

```
void for_each_bottom( Top &top, const std::function<void(Bottom &)> &fn ) {  
    for (auto t = top.begin(); t != top.end(); ++t)  
        for (auto m = t->begin(); m != t->end(); ++m)  
            for (auto b = m->begin(); b != b->end(); ++b)  
                 fn( *b );

}  

void demo( Top &top ) {
    for_each_bottom( top, []( Bottom &bottom ) {
        ExecuteSomething( bottom );
    } );
}
```

(Use Jonathan Wakely's recursive/template approach for the traversal if you prefer; these nested loops are straightforward but less general. And use a template type instead of std::function<> if you prefer that, too. I generally prefer to avoid templates unless they are needed.)

Comment: This and a couple of the other suggestions pretty much amount to the Visitor Pattern, which is a great approach of writing the iteration code just once.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Here's some semi-pseudocode for a recursive function that should do the trick:

```
void iterate(Container c)
{
    for (Iterator iter = c.begin(); iter != c.end(); iter++)
    {
        if (*iter is a Container)  // I forget how to do type-checking in C++
            iterate(*iter);
        else
            ExecuteSomething(*iter);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Something like this might be more flexible (don't remember if C++ handles function pointers differently from C/has a nicer way of utilizing them, but whatever)

```
void recursiveIterateAndExecute(Container c, void func(Container))
{
    for (Iterator iter = c.begin(); iter != c.end(); iter++)
    {
        if (*iter is a Container)  // I forget how to do type-checking in C++
            recursiveIterateAndExecute(*iter, func);
        else
            func(*iter);
    }
}
```

There are probably ways of revising these to be more in line with STL algorithms, but as I haven't done much work with C++ I can't really comment on that.

Comment: Hmm well recursion is just another way to do the same thing. I was wondering whether there was some magic code using standard libraries out there or even Boost. But currently it feels like writing a custom iterator is the way to go as @kerreck suggested.

Comment: @VikasB What kerreck suggested is pretty much what I gave you, except mine is a bit less flexible as it simply takes the top-level container and "performs the actual operation on single elements, but iteration on containers", so I imagine the actual implementation of the custom iterator would end up being fairly similar (as if I'm not mistaken, you'd have to keep track of the higher-level iterators for each current item being iterated over, and it's somewhat easier to do that using a recursive setup).

Comment: (Of course, recursion isn't necessary, but you'd probably end up using a stack[like] entity anyway to keep track of the higher iterators, so you might as well just let the compiler do it for you unless you really feel a need to optimize the code for this.)